# ASP.NET validator never validates as true

Tags: asp.net, validation

The code below has always worked, but now somehow I can't submit the form anymore even though I provide both username and password. I get no errors in backend or the Chrome Developer Console. I tried enabling/disabling all validators and found that if I add `Enabled="false"` to validator `UserNameRequired`, the form does submit. But obviously I want to have this requiredfieldvalidator enabled.
Why is this happening?

You can also see it live here (fill in a random email address/password): http://www.zorgbeurs.nl/login

```
    <table width="300">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" Text="Email" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName"/>
        </td>    
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" Text="" runat="server" Width="160px"/><br />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Enabled="false" ValidationGroup="loginuser" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="*"/>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="UserName" ValidationGroup="loginuser" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig emailadres" ValidationExpression="<%$resources:glossary,regexValidEmail %>" ID="revUsername" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"/>                
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" Text="<%$ Resources:Glossary,Password%>" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password"/>
        </td>    
        <td valign="top">
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="160px"/><br />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Enabled="false" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="loginuser" ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="*" />                    
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>    
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="loginuser" ID="LoginMember" meta:resourcekey="ibtnLogin" CommandName="Login" runat="server"/>
            <asp:CheckBox TextAlign="Right" CssClass="cblist" Font-Bold="false" ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Glossary,loginrememberme%>" /><br />

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" EnableViewState="False"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**update**

I also tried adding the ValidationExpression of revUsername expression directly in the code `[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]+`, but that does not help.

Comment: You are getting the "revUsername" validator's expression from a resource file. Has it changed in the resource file? Have you tried to include the expression directly in the code?

Comment: @HernanGuzman: Thanks, I tried that (updated in post) but it does not help...any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the username an email? @Flo

Comment: @HernanGuzman: yes it is

Answer (score 0):

I can see the required validators working in your live site without making a postback.

[image]

Regarding the email's regular expression validator, it seems that your expression is not working properly. So, I suggest you to change your regular expression, try this one:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Enabled="true" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
    ValidationGroup="loginuser" ErrorMessage="Ongeldig emailadres" 
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" 
    ID="revUsername" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Also, remember to **enable** it again in order to make it work both on client and server side.

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Thanks. Indeed they may work, but the postback is never made UNLESS I disable the revUername validator. I tried your expression and still the postback does not work...

Comment: @Flo I cannot reproduce it locally :( ... I created a webforms project with your code and the only thing that I see working incorrectly was the expression. Because of that I thinked it was your problem.

Comment: @Flo Have you tried with Enabled="true" and EnableClientScript="false"? How does it behave?

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake, I set the `Enabled` property to `false` on the requiredfieldvalidator and not the regularexpressionvalidator (I updated this now in my post). Using you latest suggestion, the password field is simply cleared when I hit submit (after a postback does seem to occur), but no login error shows (e.g. `username/password incorrect`).